# What happens to Kernel Extensions when macOS is reinstalled?

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

I believe there are a few kernel extensions running in "my" macOS.
On a (probably) unrelated issue, I've been asked to reinstall macOS. Will any extensions be gone if I reinstall macOS (Catalina)? I'll likely use the "online" reinstall way. Or will the kexts stay put?

Asking for a friend.

Comment: It depends on how you're reinstalling... are you going to format the drive before reinstalling or how are you going to approach it?

Comment: It would be reinstall as in overwrite without formatting

Answer (score 2):

The kernel extensions stuck around.

...was what happened. (not reformatting the drive)